# How to return Keycloak token after authentication via external idp

Tags: authentication, keycloak, single-sign-on

I need to log in to an external idp using keycloak. The initiator of the authorization chain is the frontend. To test this chain I request the endpoint:

https://*keycloak_uri*/realms/*realm*/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=*my-client*&redirect_uri=*web_page_uri*&response_type=code&scope=openid

where the *web_page_uri* is the uri on the site from which we came to keycloak -> then to the sso login form of the external idp.

The problem is that as a result of authentication, Keycloak creates a session, but in my project the frontend and backend work with the token.

Question: How do I return my keycloak token? How can I return it to the frontend after SSO authentication? I want to know where to find the token immediately after the redirect to the frontend and how to return the Bearer token in the Authorization header.

Comment: Your reproduction steps seems to be missing your frontend and backend steps.
You don't access Keycloak directly but first with your frontend.